# C# Nullable Ints - Compile Error

Tags: c#, nullable

Why does

```
            int? nullInt = null;
            base.Response.Data = (new BusinessLogic.RefDataManager(base.AppSettingsInfo)).SelectAppData(new DC.AppData() { AppDataKey = app_data_key != string.Empty ? app_data_key : null, AppDataTypeId = app_data_type_id != string.Empty ? int.Parse(app_data_type_id) : nullInt });
```

compile, but this

```
            base.Response.Data = (new BusinessLogic.RefDataManager(base.AppSettingsInfo)).SelectAppData(new DC.AppData() { AppDataKey = app_data_key != string.Empty ? app_data_key : null, AppDataTypeId = app_data_type_id != string.Empty ? int.Parse(app_data_type_id) : null});
```

does not? Compile error for second statement is "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and null"

DC.AppData is

```
public class AppData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "AppDataKey")]
    public string AppDataKey { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "AppDataTypeId")]
    public int? AppDataTypeId { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Why cram all that on one line, if you just used multiple lines it would be more readable and you don't have issues like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ternary operator in C# doesn't trust you to mean the `null` as a `int?`. You have to explicitly tell the C# compiler that you mean the `null` to be a `int?`...

```
base.Response.Data = (new BusinessLogic.RefDataManager(base.AppSettingsInfo)).SelectAppData(new DC.AppData() { AppDataKey = app_data_key != string.Empty ? app_data_key : null, AppDataTypeId = app_data_type_id != string.Empty ? int.Parse(app_data_type_id) : (int?)null});
```

...or that the `int.Parse(app_data_type_id)` is a `int?` by casting it...

```
(int?)int.Parse(app_data_type_id)
```

Either of the ternary yield operands must be explicitly cast to `int?`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
app_data_type_id != string.Empty ? int.Parse(app_data_type_id) : null
```

int.Parse returns an int which is not nullable

you need to cast it as an int?

```
(int?) int.Parse(app_data_type_id) : null
```

Comment: Actually, both of our answers provide a working solution. It seems that either of the ternary yield operands need to be explicitly `int?`, but not both.